# Присвоение полю значений другого поля

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql

Здравствуйте.

Есть две таблицы в бд MS Sql Server: table 1 и table 2.
В них обеих есть поле с названием W, которое обозначает пол. Мне надо перенести значения из table 2 в table 1, но проблема в том что:
table 1.W = 1 или table 1.W =2   
а table 2.W = "М" или table 2.W= "Ж"

Как сделать так, чтобы поменять значения table1.W на "М" или "Ж" или table2.W на 1 или 2.  
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [CASE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement.html), например:

```
insert into table1(W,...)
select case W when 'M' then 1 else 2 end, ... from table2
```

Comment: Спачибо большое, помогло !